# Как убрать подергивание при наведении на элемент?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

http://jsfiddle.net/rinatoptimus/ujx8yumh/ - при наведении красный текст и картинка мэйл ру всплывают, но если поводить курсор по красному тексту, то он начинает подергиваться. Как это можно исправить?

```js
$('#alpha_wrapper').hover(function() {
    $('p').toggleClass('t1 t2', 1000);
});
```

```css
.grayscale {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    /* For Webkit browsers */
    filter: gray;
    /* For IE 6 - 9 */
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
    /* Transition for Webkit browsers */
}
.grayscale:hover {
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: none;
}
/* мой код начало */
 .grayscale {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background: url(http://www.cheesetoast.co.uk/cheesepress/wp- content/uploads/2013/02/apple.png);
    no-repeat;
}
.icon {
    width: 135px;
    height: 28px;
}
.appear img {
    /*padding: 1em 0;*/
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(60%, 200px, 200px);
}
.appear:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(85px, 85px, 0px);
}
p {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -70px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    color: red;
    width:75px;
    height:18px;
    background:green;
}
.t1 {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
    /*transform: translate3d(60%, 200px, 200px);*/
    transform: translate3d(60%, 200px, 200px);
}
.t2 {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(5px, -25px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="grayscale appear" id="alpha_wrapper" />
    <img class="icon" src="https://img.imgsmail.ru/r/default/portal/0.1.29/logo.png" />
    </div>
    <p>dhdfghdfgh</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

`<p>` перекрывает `#alpha_wrapper`, поэтому `#alpha_wrapper` теряет `hover`, так как `<p>` не находится внутри него.

Можно, как в [следующем](http://jsfiddle.net/ujx8yumh/1/) варианте, отключить обработку событий для `<p>`, но тогда для него не будет работать, к примеру, `hover`.

Также можно обойтись без JS, ведь в CSS есть селектор для последующего элемента: `#alpha_wrapper:hover + p {`